# cakephp sql log is correct, not returning data

Tags: sql, database, cakephp

I'm creating a simple view function, after checking my sql log its correct, However my view is not printing the information.

```
SELECT `AccountsUser`.`id`, `AccountsUser`.`account_id`
  FROM `pra`.`accounts_users` AS `AccountsUser`
 WHERE `user_id` = 14   

SELECT `Template`.`id`, `Template`.`name`, `Template`.`description`,
       `Template`.`account_id`
  FROM `pra`.`templates` AS `Template`
 WHERE `Template`.`account_id` = (10)
```

The `account_id=10` but it isn't printing out the templates related to the `account.id`

```
function view(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'View Templates');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');
    $this->layout='home_layout';

     $this->Template->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Account')));
    $templates = $this->Auth->user('name');
    $accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('list', array('fields'=>array('id', 'account_id'),'conditions' =>  array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));       
    $templates=$this->Template->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Template.account_id' => $accounts)));

    $this->set('template', $templates);
    $this->set('account'. $accounts);}
```

Here is the view

```
<table width="100%" border="1">

            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Template Name</th>
                    <th>Template Description</th>

                </tr>

                <?php foreach($template as $templates): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['templates']['id']; ?> </td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['templates']['name']; ?> </td>

                    </tr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>


            </table>
```

id like it to print a list of templates related to the `account.id`

Comment: You have `$this->set('account'. $accounts);` instead of `$this->set('account', $accounts);` (comma instead of full stop). Does that prevent the execution from reaching the right place in the view?

Comment: Also, have you verified with `debug( $templates );` in the controller what the query returns?

Comment: fixed it but doesn't change anything, also the debug produces nothing. just array(), this is what puzzeles me because the sqllog  prints out the correct statement

Comment: And if you run the same query in e.g. phpMyAdmin you get results?

Comment: no returns 0 results, there should be 1 result

Comment: Well the problem doesn't have anything to do with CakePHP then, does it? You just don't have any records in the database that would have account_id 10.

Comment: no i realized the issue, the templates add is saving account_users.id, NOT accounts_users.account_id, which is why nothing is being returned

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
        <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Template Name</th>
                <th>Template Description</th>

            </tr>

            <?php if(!empty($template))
                  {
                    foreach($template as $templates)
                    {?>
                        <tr>
                           <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['Template']['id']; ?> </td>
                           <td align='center'><?php echo $templates['Template']['name']; ?> </td>
                        </tr>
                 <?php 
                    }// end of foreach
                  }
                  else
                  {?>

                        <tr> <td>No Templates Found.</td></tr>

                  <?php
                  }?>
        </table>
```

Comment: still isn't grabbing the template from the database though :(

Comment: i dont think the variable has been set correctly, the account.id has been set correctly but this line isnt working properly, the setting of $accounts returns the correct information  $templates=$this->Template->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Template.account_id' => $accounts)));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14977/discussion-between-arun-jain-and-user1417448)

Comment: array(
 (int) 3 => '10'
)

3 is the accounts_users.id, 10 is the account_id

Comment: it wont allow me to type to you in the chat

Comment: its loading no templates found though